# Difference between a module and an extension in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

What is the difference between a module and an extension in Postgres

Why a module creation use the same syntax as the extension creation

```
CREATE EXTENSION modulename;
```

Answer (score 6):

Basically there is none. Before version 9.1 there was no `EXTENSION` system so they where known as modules. Since then they have been installed as extensions. See [9.1 release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/release-9-1.html):

> All contrib modules are now installed with CREATE EXTENSION rather than by manually invoking their SQL scripts ...

So a module was a set of scripts you had to run yourself and an `Extension` is the same scripts run by `CREATE EXTENSION`. A script packaging system that makes it easier to create/upgrade/drop an extension(module).